# Help choosing between two frame sizes based on my dimensions

Tags: frames, bike-fit

I would really appreciate some help choosing a size of bike frame. I am stuck between choosing the large or the extra large.

I may go down the route of getting professionally checked on the bike, but there is every chance that since this is a frame company a long way from my house I won't be able to get it properly checked before I try and place an order, only testing on equivalent bikes. I have not decided if I am going for flat bars or drop bars, but more likely drop bars.

**These are the bike sizes:**

[image]

**These are my measurements:**

[image]

```
A: 186cm (6ft 1inch)
B:
C: 88cm
D:
E: 62cm (armpit to bottom of thumb as per picture)
F:
```

Any help would be really appreciated. My feeling is that the large is the right size, but from my preliminary reading it looks like the extra large may be closer?

Thank you

Comment: Theres a decent amount of preference. A lot of people can go between 2 sizes in a model, but one may be better. You'll need to ride it or find a similar bike and ride it to find out.

Comment: A test ride is the only true answer.  Sorry if that's not useful.

Answer (score 1):

When in doubt, the best is to try the bike.

Dimensions are important from an anthropometric point of vue especially to prevent injuries and such. So in that perspective if you're kind of in-between sizes the choice will be guided by your sensations.

I know cyclists that prefer oversize and others that prefer undersize, it depends on how much you lean on the bike and that kind of factors.

So the best way to do it is to spot the extremities on your size spectrum and try bikes that match, you will feel what is natural for you.

I personnaly ride an old steelframe oversized roadbike and it's feels awesome.